# CodenameOne Mobile app throws SSL Exception connecting to https server with real certificates (not self signed)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, codenameone

I have an Amazon AWS environment running a spring boot server app with https endpoints. (https://www.myapp.com:8443) A real (not self signed) certificate for www.myapp.com has been installed on the server.

When connecting from an Android release app on a real device (installed via OTA email) I see the exception :

```
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException - 
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for 
certification path not found.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for 
certification path not found.
```

In the Simulator I have added my real site certificate to my IntelliJ java cacerts file and that works fine. From within the simulator all my https calls to the AWS box work fine.

When building the Android app I added the real cert to the keystore and specified that keystore via the CN1 Preferences for the Android settings. This built fine but generated the above exception when run on a real device.

Using a self signed cert via CN1 and deployed on a real device also failed in the same manner.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

The keystore in Android builds is used for signing so adding certificates to it is irrelevant as once the APK is signed it won't change anything. If the certificate isn't available to Android or Apple then it's not a great certificate to use. If you open the native browser on Android and the site loads correctly then it should work with the app as well.

Comment: If I open up chrome on android the site loads up and the padlock is closed ie secure. Clicking on the padlock in chrome reports :

"Chrome verified that Starfield Secure Certificate Authority - G2 issued this websites certificate"

"Your connection to www.xxxxx.com:8443 is encrypted using a modern cipher suite...."

Comment: update : the app works on ios devices but still fails on android. Doing some more research on Starfield CA showed a bunch of issues regarding java different versions of the jdk having missing certs for Starfield in cacerts etc. I decided to buy another cert from another CA and all now seems ok - on both android and ios. Thx for help and clarification as always.